# Inserting a div after the second image jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using the code bellow to insert a div after the first image and it works great..
Is it possible to insert it after the second image?

my code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".gdl-blog-full").find("img:first").after("<div id='1' style='width:800px; height:90px; float: left; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:15px;'><div class='gad' style='width: 728px; height:90px; float: left; margin-left: 36px;'></div></div>");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [:eq](http://jqapi.com/#p=eq-selector) is same as `:nth()`

```
$(".gdl-blog-full").find("img:nth(1)")
```

> :nth(),:eq() index starts from 0

or [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$(".gdl-blog-full").find("img:nth-child(2)")
```

> :nth-child() index starts from 1

or [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$(".gdl-blog-full").find("img").eq(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use eq : [further reading :eq](http://jqapi.com/#p=eq-selector)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {                     
    $(".gdl-blog-full").find("img:eq(1)").after("<div id='1' style='width:800px; height:90px; float: left; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:15px;'><div class='gad' style='width: 728px; height:90px; float: left; margin-left: 36px;'></div></div>");
});
```